# Why am I not able to call a parent-class method from module?

Tags: ruby, module, class-method

This is my [code](https://repl.it/Bq8c):

```
module RubyEditExtComponent
    def eventExt
        watchExt "banana"
    end
end

class RubyEditExt
    def self.watchExt(value)
        puts value
    end

    include RubyEditExtComponent
end

RubyEditExt.new.eventExt
```

I want to call a specific (parent) class method that will output the value I'll pass to it. But it says `undefined method watchExt`.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be, what you are trying to do is to extend your class `RubyEditExt` with functionality from the module `RubyEditExtComponent`. This has nothing to do with inheritance (ChildClass < ParentClass). Usually you will do this to modularize functionality, which keeps your classes clean and the modules are reusable. Such modules are called mixins.

See the example below. This way you can extend your class with instance methods which you can call for every object of your class or you define class methods for the class which will include the module.

```
module RubyEditExtComponent
  def self.included(klass)
    klass.instance_eval do
      include InstanceMethods
      extend ClassMethods
    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def eventExt
      watchExt "banana"
    end
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def eventExt2
      self.new.watchExt "banana"
    end
  end
end

class RubyEditExt
  include RubyEditExtComponent

  def watchExt(value)
    puts value
  end
end
```

The method `self.included` is called at the inclusion of the module (`include RubyEditExtComponent`) and it receives the class which includes it. Now you can call the instance method for an object of your class:

```
RubyEditExt.new.eventExt
banana
 => nil
```

Or you call the class method. In this method I create an instance (`self.new`) of the class which includes the module (`self == RubyEditExt`) and then I call the instance method `watchExt` for it.

```
RubyEditExt.eventExt2
banana
=> nil
```

Answer (score 1):

`watchExt` is called from the instance method, so it either should be an instance method itself:

```
class RubyEditExt
  def watchExt(value) # NO self
    puts value
  end
  ...
end
```

or it should be called as class method:

```
module RubyEditExtComponent
  def eventExt
    self.class.watchExt "banana"
  end
end
```

Comment: Uhm, I need to call a `class method` from an `instance method` using a single "keyword" (in this case, the single keyword is `watchExt`). How can I do it?

Comment: This is another question, would you mind to express what are you trying to achieve? One way would be to `self.class.public_send :watchExt, "banana"`. Frankly: I do not completely understand the requirements. What does mean “using a single keyword”?

Comment: I want to use custom "keywords" inside my instance method, that perform some task. So in this case, "myPrinter" would for example put custom text on the console. I'm on Environment that (for example) writing "watch" will print on its console (so, basically perform a put with custom settings) the text. I need the same.

Comment: Then `self.class.public_send :watchExt, "banana"` should meet your requirements. The atom `:watchExt` might be set dynamically.

Comment: But where should I put this? "banana" is a string that is dynamic. Now I can write `watchExt "banana"`, than some line above `watchExt "hello"`. Its somethings like a logger...

Comment: Change `watchExt "banana"` to `self.class.public_send :watchExt, "banana"`. I still do not understand what are you trying to accomplish and I think it is a matter of wrong design. Please try to restate the question, mentioning all the circumstances, since the OP I had answered already.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104649/discussion-between-markzzz-and-mudasobwa).